# Chart.js grouped stacked bars

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to do stacked bar charts but also group some of them together and possibly color them slightly different.

I've got data as follows:

```
regionsSelected = ['North', 'South'];

var variables = {
    'var1' : {
    0 : {'North' : 3, 'South' : 4},
    1 : {'North' : 3.5, 'South' : 4.5}
    },
  'var2' : {
    0 : {'North' : 5, 'South' : 5},
    1 : {'North' : 5.5, 'South' : 5.5}
  }
}
//myChart.data.labels = ['var1','var2'];
var bgColor = {
    'North': 'rgb(152,78,163)',
  'South': 'rgb(77,175,74)'}

var bgColor_paired = {
    0: 
  {
    'North': 'rgb(152,78,163)',
    'South': 'rgb(77,175,74)'},
  1: 
  {
    'North': 'rgb(122,78,163)',
    'South': 'rgb(77,125,74)'}
}

for (var random_var in variables) {
    for (x=0;x<2;x++) {
    var y = x;
    var y = y.toString();
    var label = random_var + y;
    console.log(label);
    myChart.data.labels.push(label);
  }
}
for (var region in regionsSelected) {
    stacked_data = [];
  for (x=0;x<2;x++) {

    for (var random_var in variables) {
        var_data = variables[random_var][x][regionsSelected[region]];
        stacked_data.push(var_data); 
    }
  }
   myChart.data.datasets.push({
            label: regionsSelected[region],
            backgroundColor: bgColor[regionsSelected[region]],
            hoverBackgroundColor: bgColor[regionsSelected[region]],
            borderColor: bgColor[regionsSelected[region]],
            data: stacked_data,
          });
}
```

I want to compare the x's of a number of random_vars for a number of regions with each other. So the region's are stacked per random_var[x] and I want to group these by random_var (so you can compare random_var1[x1] very easy to random_var1[x2] and then look to the next random_var etc.

Currently, I have the regions stacked and the random_var1[x1] en [x2] next to each other, but not yet grouped. Ideally I would color x1 and x2 slightly different so you can more easily compare random_var1[x1] with random_var2[x1] (because those bars will have the same color).

I made a fiddle with everything in it (including additional colors), but I don't know how to do the grouping:

https://jsfiddle.net/CorneelDragon/o6vkLm0d/39/

EDIT: My 'solution' would be this: https://jsfiddle.net/CorneelDragon/o6vkLm0d/74/. The bars are not grouped however, I think I need to implement the additional code from the github-comment

Comment: Can you add a sketch of what you want to achieve?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616862/5090771)...